# In Elixir, should I be using structs to model data contracts in an SDK I'm building for an API?

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

I'm new to Elixir, and functional programming in general really, and I'm looking for a little guidance on whether it's the 'right' thing to do to to build struct models of data contracts in an SDK I'm building for the Xero API.

The gist of the SDK is that it exposes the endpoints - and operations on those endpoints - of the Xero API, performs OAuth1.0a authorisation, and then makes web requests to the API. What should my SDK be returning to the consumer?

Should I

- just return the raw HTTPoison response and leave it up to the consumer to handle?
- use Poison to deserialize the returned JSON payload into a map and return that?
- create structs for each of the data contracts and use Poison to decode the JSON string into those structs with a little brute force?

Is there some other more correct way to do this in Elixir/functional programming?

The API also supports PUT/POST operations and so if using structs, the structs can be supplied to these operations and encoded down to a JSON string.

The data contracts in the API are pretty complex with a quite a bit of nesting.
[You can see an example of one in the documentation](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/invoices)

[This is the SDK repo for anyone interested](https://github.com/MJMortimer/elixero)

Comment: I do not see what this question has to do with a language paradigm: be it functional, imperative, OO, or even not-yet-invented. You should produce something, no matter what, depending only on your understanding or your consumer’s needs. When you have no idea about consumer’s needs, it’s probably better to stay as generic as possible (hence maps). Whether you expect your consumers to be Elixir-based and you have an opportunity to share the structures code with them—use structs, they will have instantiation out of the box. Hereby I vote to close the question as opinion based.

Comment: So if you are passing a lot of information throughout all the different functions that you will have in your application then a struct would be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether you should transform requests payload into Structs as soon as they reach you, then answer is yes. Structs are bare maps underneath but they only use `:atoms` as keys which means they fetch faster.

It is also easier to read for fellow programmers that may maintain your code later. I also suggest reading [this article.](https://engineering.appcues.com/2016/02/02/too-many-dicts.html)